# VHDL Finite State Machine - Is the reset really necessary?

Tags: vhdl, reset, xilinx, state-machine, synthesis

I'm still learning VHDL for synthesis purposes on a custom Xilinx Spartan-6 based board. My design includes a lot of FSM and I've just learned in a previous question that the single process implementation is a lot better and much easier to use.

I also learned that initialization values for signals are actually synthetizable.

So here is the question: do I really need a reset signal to put the FSM in idle with default outputs, **IF** I don't need to interrupt the FSM mid flow OR I already have another signal that stops it?

Comment: You can take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23000528/1583598) for a list of reasons why resets are a good idea. Yes you can often get away without them but you will pay in the future if you persist in doing that with complex designs or need to port to an ASIC.

Comment: Read @KevinThibedeau's link in his comment above.  I could not up vote it enough myself.   Without a dedicated reset, you will have fun adding reset to your design should you need to port it to an ASIC, CPLD, or Microsemi Fuselink part.  It would be better if a vendor worked the other way around - all designs have reset and vendors provide a means to transform reset into their preferred initialization method.  Recommendions to not use reset is simply a vendor insuring that you will continue to use their parts - seems like marketing has subsumed engineering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's see what is the Xilinx appraoch on reset :

Xilinx FPGA includes "Global Set/Reset" module which automatically set all signals at their initialisation values at start-up. The initialisation value is declared as follow:

```
signal foo : std_logic := '0';
--                         ^ initialisation value
```

When designing a new part of code, you have to think twice for each bit if it needs to be reset by something else than the GSR, because using your own global reset is actually using a second global reset.

For your FSM, it has a startup state (IDLE) and will never be reset in the whole bitstream life. We can say at first that the FSM do not need a reset. But if you just do it like it, you'll be exposed to metastability issues. The GSR is quite slow to deassert its reset and it does it asynchronously. All flip-flop won't be released at the same time and your FSM can go in an illegal state.

So, **use a local reset for your FSM** (and counters as well).

***To complete the reset question:***

- avoiding the use of global reset has better place and route result, which leads to less timing errors. A global reset uses the same network as others signals in the design, it prevents some routing resource to be available for other signal distribution.
- if you really need the use of a reset, prefer an active high synchronous reset or at least an active high reset, activated asynchronously and deactivated synchronously. Active High because Xilinx Flip-Flop uses active high SET and RESET, synchronous to avoid metastability problem.

***Workaround:***

A solution to avoid the local reset on the FSM could be the use of a bufgce module at clock entry. At startup, this module do not feed the design with the clock and wait for some clock cycles before enabling the clock. Only a local reset is used here to manage the `enable` input of the BUFGCE and the reset of the FGPA is reset free. 
I don't know how many clock cycles have to be waited, but it can do it. The first approach is still the best for now.

Comment: These informations are from a xilinx ppt file I have but I can't remember where I got it. I'll try to find an internet link.

Comment: Metastability is only a potential issue if the design is such that the state machine can transition immediately after GSR/reset.

Comment: @fru1tbat I agree but it can happen. The main idea is to remember that GSR is slow and asynchonous, and that each part of the design have to be thought twice.

Comment: here is the xilinx file on reset for series 7 : [ppt file](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xilinx.com%2Ftraining%2Fdownloads%2F7-series-slice-flip-flops.pptx&ei=hwS9VLPGIY7uaI_5gIAD&usg=AFQjCNHgPDvMupoSeQyY7IFZxFQEaxewQA&sig2=qkwWI75Eq2oW9LaRC_vEdw&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d2s). The one I have is for series 6 but can't find it on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If your state variable is initialised to 'idle', then having a reset which forces it to 'idle' is only useful if you need it for some other reason. One major example would be if the state machine has states, where, on noticing an erroneous input, it deliberately stops to wait for something to reset it, before resuming normal operation.

The machine might also be running from a clock that is not guaranteed to be glitch free, or is for some reason not 100% reliable. In this case it can be sensible to include a reset, so that something like a host processor or other FPGA logic can somehow detect that the state machine is no longer working, and reset it.

Lots of people seem to have a reset signal in most processes they write, but it's perfectly valid to rely on signal and output initialisation values, if the machine then meets your design requirements. If all the reset does is assert itself briefly during startup, and never again, I would say there's not much point in it.

[EDIT] Per other answers, relying on initialisation values is normally only valid in SRAM-based FPGA designs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of white papers from Xilinx that address the issue and they actually show up as the first two items googling for *Xilinx reset*.

These are WP272 [Get Smart About Reset: Think Local, Not Global](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp272.pdf) and WP275 [Get your Priorities Right – Make your Design Up to 50% Smaller](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp275.pdf).

The first paper does a fair job of pointing out where you should use a reset as opposed to where you can depend on configuration and default values.

The second paper also points out that the reasons why are vendor and technology dependent.  You could also note the reason for eliminating 'unnecessary' resets is to preserve place and route resources.

Because you don't elaborate the details of a Finite State Machine implementation while asking if the reset is really necessary, note the claim in WP272 where an asynchronous reset can be deleterious for a One Hot State Machine which would benefit from configuration load (a default value), synchronous reset or a clock synchronized asynchronous reset.

Your VHDL code with (*proper*) resets is ultimately more portable, should your design ever be intended for an ASIC or some other non- bit image loaded solutions.  For those soft loaded designs the ultimate reset is embodied in a configuration load.

Otherwise the purpose is to conserve place and route resources.